# Strings in c and printing the string by printf

Tags: c, string

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char s1[]="harry ";
    char s2[]="is a friend of ";
    char s3[]="ravi";
    char s4[20];
    char s5[20];
    strcpy(s4,strcat(s1,s2));
    strcpy(s5,strcat(s4,s3));
    printf("%s", s5);
    return 0;
}
```

Why I m getting segmentation fault here why it's not printing by use of printf..??

I tried using printf it wasn't printing but with the use of puts it was printing why so ??
Please anyone do tell me what's the fault in this

Comment: The string `harry is a friend of ravi\0` (with `\0` for the trailing null) is more than 20 bytes long.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/995714)

Comment: Where do you think the results of your calls to `strcat` go?

Comment: `strcat()` modifies its first argument in place, it doesn't return a new string.

Comment: So `strcat(s1, s2)` causes undefined behavior because `s1` isn't big enough to hold the combined strings.

Comment: Ohk I got this But why it is printing if I use puts instead of printf ..?? @AKX

Comment: @Riyaagrwal sheer luck, probably.

Comment: Undefined behavior _can_ be "appears to work fine." This is probably the worst possible result.

Comment: Thanku But why it is printing when I use puts instead of printf?? @AKX

Comment: If I write puts(s5) instead of printf("%s",s5) then why it is printing when the size of s4 and s5 strings are not enough to hold them ?? Please do help

Comment: @Riyaagrwal it's _undefined behaviour_ (google that term). You're overwriting a buffer, any bets are off, anything can happen including what you expect.

Comment: @Riyaagrwal "why it is printing when I use puts instead of printf?" - it's printed in both cases with difference that with puts() it adds '\n' and so that buffer is flushed before crash, with printf it crashes before output buffer would've been flushed at exit.

Answer (score 5):

`strcat()` puts the concatenated strings in its first argument. Since `s1` is only long enough to hold the string it was initialized with, you can't use it as the destination when concatenating to itself.

Instead of using `strcat()` as the source of `strcpy()`, you should copy the first string and then concatenate the second string in the destination.

You also need to make the destination strings larger, so they have room for the final string (including the terminating null).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char s1[]="harry ";
    char s2[]="is a friend of ";
    char s3[]="ravi";
    char s4[30];
    char s5[30];
    strcpy(s4, s1);
    strcat(s4, s2);
    strcpy(s5, s4);
    strcat(s5, s3);
    printf("%s\n", s5);
    return 0;
}
```

You can ensure that the destination strings are long enough by declaring the sizes dynamically:

```
char s4[sizeof s1 + sizeof s2];
char s5[sizeof s4 + sizeof s3];
```

Comment: The `strcpy` is unnecessary for the first case vs. `strcat` if `s4` and `s5` are initialized properly. E.g. `char s4[30] = {0};` Or: `char s4[30] = "";`

Comment: @Chris Why use `strcat()` if you knw you want to overwrite?

Comment: Possibly also worth noting: so long as one's compiler supports VLAs, you can ensure `s4` and `s5` have sufficient capacity with something like: `char s4[sizeof(s1) + sizeof(s2) + sizeof(s3)];`

Comment: for the sake of consistency?

Comment: @Chris I did consider writing that, but decided it was more complex than necessary for this simple example

Comment: And notice that that adds extra space, since it counts the null terminators in all the inputs.

Comment: It does, but it's cheaper than calling `strlen` and two extra bytes shouldn't hurt.

Answer (score 3):

There are quite a few problems in your interpretation of C-strings work.

```
strcat(s1,s2)
```

Refer [man page for strcat](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcat), the description clearly states the following:

> The strcat() function appends the src string to the dest string, overwriting the terminating null byte ('\0') at the end of dest, and then adds a terminating null byte. The strings may not overlap, and the dest string must have enough space for the result. If dest is not large enough, program behavior is unpredictable; buffer overruns are a favorite avenue for attacking secure programs.

In your code, its quite clear that `s1` isn't long enough to accommodate contents of `s2`. So, this invokes Undefined Behavior.

If you want to make this code functional without a lot of changes -- I recommend increasing the size of `s4` and `s5` to a safe value and using `snprint()` for accumulating strings rather than blindly using `strcat`. Something like below:

```
snprintf(s4, sizeof(s4), "%s%s", s1, s2);
snprintf(s5, sizeof(s5), "%s%s", s4, s3);
```

You might err to argue why it works with `puts(s5)`.
In your original code, the buffer overflow caused undefined behavior, but in some/most cases, the undefined behavior may not immediately result in a crash or an error. The behavior of undefined code can be unpredictable.
For example, the code with `puts` poses an error later.

```
harry is a friend of ravi
*** stack smashing detected ***: terminated
```

You cannot conclude that things work with `puts`. It is important to note that relying on undefined behavior is not a safe or reliable programming practice.

Comment: An optimised release build doesn't have stack smashing detection, so it will do something else.

Comment: @OrangeDog gcc -O99 -Os still detects smashing, clang not

Comment: @OrangeDog -- Yes, and something else would be a bit harder to debug and understand as well at this point for OP.